# Get 2 different data from 1 kafka topic into 2 dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-kafka-integration

I have a homework like this:

1. Use python to read json files in 2 folders song_data and log_data.
2. Use Python Kafka to publish a mixture of both song_data and log_data file types into a Kafka topic.
3. Use Pyspark to consume data from the above Kafka topic.
4. Use Stream processing to consume messages from song_data and create 2 dataframes, songs and artitst. and from log_data generate dataframe as users, time.
5. Create songplays from dataframes of dimension tables.

I have a problems with read different file from 1 topic, 2 folder containt json file but 1 is song data and 1 is log. How can I get their own data from just 1 topics ?

Comment: can you show the code that works for you partially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unclear why you cannot just use two topics, one for each file. Especially if they don't have matching schemas, which will be important for SparkSQL.

> How can I get their own data from just 1 topics ?

It begins at step 2.

Write the data to your single topic in a format like so (`content` used for example purposes only)

```
{"type": "song", "content": "..."}
```

or

```
{"type": "log", "content": "..."}
```

Then, in SparkSQL, you can do something like this

```
df = spark.readStream.format("kafka")... # TODO: apply a schema to the data to get a "type" column
song_data = df.where(df("type") == "song").select("content")
log_data = df.where(df("type") == "log").select("content")
```

You could also do the same filtering in Python-Kafka and not need dataframes or a Spark environment.

Comment: Thank u, its not my need but i think it will help me in that case